# I need to filter only duplicated lines from many files using bash

Tags: bash

I have the following three files

filea

```
a
bc
cde
```

fileb

```
a
bc
cde
frtdff
```

filec

```
a
bc
cddeeer
erer34
```

I am able to filter by the duplicated lines from these three files.
I am using the following command

```
ls file* | wc -l
```

which returns 3. Then, I am launching

```
sort file* | uniq --count --repeated | awk '{ if ($1 == 3) { print $2} }'
```

The last command returns precisely what I need, only in case I am not creating more files starting with "file".

But, in case I have thousands of files that need to be created during the time a script is running , I should get an exact number of files coming retrieved from this command

```
n=`ls file* | wc -l`
sort file* | uniq --count --repeated | awk '{ if ($1 == $n) { print $2} }'
```

Unfortunately, variable n is not accepted inside the if condition of the awk command.

My issue is that I am not able to use the value of the variable n as a comparison criteria inside an if conditional that is part of awk command.

Comment: `awk -v n=$n '$1 == n { print $2 }'`

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```sh
awk '!line[$0]++' file*
```

This  will print only once any string even if present in several files and or in same file.

Comment: They only want the lines that are repeated in all the files.